# select and poll not work correctly

Tags: java, c, linux, epoll

I writing a auto stream multiplexer in java which, must read vaious amount of FileDescriptors. To read the file descriptors (or socket etc. which have FileDescriptor), I need a precise soultion, if I have some descriptors and there is no event don't iterate trouth all. And here is som method in linux: select,poll. I tried to use this methods but without success. the native codes is:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_hu_ddsi_java_Native_JUnix_select(JNIEnv * env,jobject obj,jobjectArray fds,long timeout_s,long timeout_us)
{

    int len = env->GetArrayLength(fds);
    jclass cls = env->FindClass("java/io/FileDescriptor");
    jfieldID fid = env->GetFieldID(cls, "fd", "I");
    fd_set watch;
    int buf = 0;
    int max = 0;

    for(int i=0;i <  len;i++)
    {
        FD_SET( buf=(int) env->GetIntField(env->GetObjectArrayElement(fds, i),fid),&watch);
        if(buf>max)
            max = buf;
    }

    struct timeval *timeout = (timeval*) malloc(sizeof(struct timeval));
    timeout->tv_sec = timeout_s;
    timeout->tv_usec = timeout_us;

    return select(max+1, &watch, NULL,NULL,timeout);
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_hu_ddsi_java_Native_JUnix_poll(JNIEnv * env,jobject obj,jlongArray pollfds,int timeout_ms)
{
    unsigned int nfds = env->GetArrayLength(pollfds);

    void* pointerfor = malloc(nfds*(sizeof(void*)));

    for(int i=0;i <  nfds;i++)
        env->GetLongArrayRegion(pollfds,i,1,(jlong*) pointerfor+(sizeof(void*)*i));

    return poll( ((struct pollfd*)pointerfor), nfds,timeout_ms);
}

JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_hu_ddsi_java_Native_JUnix_pollfd(JNIEnv * env,jobject obj,jobject fd,jshort events,jshort revents)
{
    jclass cls = env->FindClass("java/io/FileDescriptor");
    jfieldID fid = env->GetFieldID(cls, "fd", "I");

    struct pollfd *pfd = (pollfd*) malloc(sizeof( pollfd));
        pfd->fd = env->GetIntField(fd,fid);
        pfd->events = events;
        pfd->revents = 0x0;

    return (jlong) pfd; 
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_hu_ddsi_java_Native_JUnix_pollfdfd(JNIEnv * env,jobject obj,jlong pfd_struct)
{
    return ((struct pollfd*)pfd_struct)->fd;
}

JNIEXPORT jshort JNICALL Java_hu_ddsi_java_Native_JUnix_pollfdevents(JNIEnv * env,jobject obj,jlong pfd_struct)
{
    return ((struct pollfd*)pfd_struct)->events;
}

JNIEXPORT jshort JNICALL Java_hu_ddsi_java_Native_JUnix_pollfdrevents(JNIEnv * env,jobject obj,jlong pfd_struct)
{
    return ((struct pollfd*)pfd_struct)->revents;
}
```

And a test code in java:

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Throwable

        final FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("/var/log/apache2/access.log");
        long st = JUnix.pollfd(is.getFD(),(short)( JUnix.POLLIN|JUnix.POLLPRI ));
        int len = 0;
        while(true)
        {

            System.out.println("ava:"+(len = is.available()));

            for(int i=0;i < len;i++)
                System.out.print((char) is.read());

//          JUnix.select(new FileDescriptor[]{is.getFD()},5,0);

            System.out.println("pollretval: "+JUnix.poll(new long[]{st},-1));
            System.out.println("revent: "+JUnix.pollfdrevents(st));
            System.out.println("pollfd: "+JUnix.pollfdfd(st));
        }
    }
```

And when I browse, I should see new lines in the terminal, but it will be blocked forever...
if I modify the timeout I se the now lines in my terminal.

Sometimes the code getting crazy and print infintly:

```
ava:0
pollretval: 1
revent: 0
pollfd: 10
```

this result is interesting, fileDescriptor is same, native poll returned with the modified fd numbers, but in the pollfd stuct the revent field is... it should modified if event occurred.
 I tested, pointers is are in good location (as result shows), and a simple C code is do same result (i not finded InputStream.available like method in C for FD so I don't see how many byte are availble in stream, but its wait forever)

What do I wrong?

Comment: If i give positive timeout, its unleashed, wake up infinitly whitout waiting.

Answer (score 1):

In `Java_hu_ddsi_java_Native_JUnix_select` you need to add a call to

```
FD_ZERO(&watch);
```

to initialise your `fd_set`.

You also leak `timeout`.  You need to either `free` it after `select` returns or, better, just declare it on the stack

```
struct timeval timeout;
timeout.tv_sec = timeout_s;
timeout.tv_usec = timeout_us;
return select(max+1, &watch, NULL,NULL,&timeout);
```

There is a similar leak of `pointerfor` in `Java_hu_ddsi_java_Native_JUnix_poll`.  Use of `malloc` may be appropriate so you may need to `free` the pointers before returning.

Comment: FD_ZERO() not solved the problem, but thanks for memory management tips:)

Comment: linux select is limited to first 1024 file descriptors. see FD_SETSIZE. if you have to add a descriptor > 1024, things will go wrong (undefined behavior , often crash ). prefer poll().